# how to change CNN model to Wide convolution in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I am learning CNN, I want to change CNN model with Wide Convolution by pytorch, who can help?

```
self.conv23 = nn.Conv2d(Ci, len(Ks) * Co, (3, Co), padding=1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/workspace/pycharmworkspace/cnn-text-classification-pytorch-update/main.py", line 137, in <module>
    train.train(train_iter, dev_iter, cnn, args)
  File "E:\workspace\pycharmworkspace\cnn-text-classification-pytorch-update\train.py", line 40, in train
    logit = model(feature)
  File "C:\Users\bamtercelboo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 206, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "E:\workspace\pycharmworkspace\cnn-text-classification-pytorch-update\model.py", line 206, in forward
    x21 = self.conv(x11, self.conv23)  #(N,Co)
  File "E:\workspace\pycharmworkspace\cnn-text-classification-pytorch-update\model.py", line 91, in conv
    x = F.relu(conv(x)).squeeze(3)  # (N,Co,W)
  File "C:\Users\bamtercelboo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 206, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bamtercelboo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 237, in forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
  File "C:\Users\bamtercelboo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 43, in conv2d
    return f(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: kernel size should be greater than zero, but got kT: 3 kH: 200 kW: 0 at d:\downloads\pytorch-master-1\torch\lib\thnn\generic/VolumetricConvolutionMM.c:23
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might need is adjusting the groups parameter in the Conv2D layers.